# How to send request, by using RESTFul web services?

Tags: java, ios, spring, rest

I have sucessfully received value from  http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting by using RESTFul and json web services. But unable to send my own text box value in request to my own server running apache on another machine.

my  working code -:

```
- (IBAction)fetchGreeting;
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:NULL];
             self.greetingId.text = [[greeting objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue];
             self.greetingContent.text = [greeting objectForKey:@"content"];
         }
     }];
}
```

But it stop working when i change NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"];  value to my own server address, and also unable to wrap my own text box value in request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually add our textfield data into the request like this.

NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting/%@",textFied.text];

Can you show how your URL look like?

Comment: Thankyou sir,  i want to submit this tex box value to another machine running tomcat server  so what url shuld i pass, i have tried with "http://ip address:8080/app" but failed

Comment: There should be an API which can accept your data.              NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:8080/controller",ipAddress];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];
    
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];

Comment: mam here controller means application name to which i am submitting

Comment: No  You cant directly send to an app, unless an API is already created for it.

Comment: can you name any api for communicating iphone with java server